# PHP Deprecation Warning (class extends WP_Widget {)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, warnings

I'm receiving a Deprecated PHP warning on my wordpress site that states ... Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; video_widget has a deprecated constructor.

It's pointing to line 5 which I've pasted below;

```
class video_widget extends WP_Widget {


/** constructor -- name this the same as the class above */
function video_widget() {
    parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'Video Widget');
}

/** @see WP_Widget::widget -- do not rename this */
function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract( $args );
    $title          = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
    $message        = $instance['message'];
    ?>
          <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
              <?php if ( $title )
                    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>
                                                    <div class="omc-video-container">
                                                            <?php echo $message; ?>
                                                    </div>
          <?php echo $after_widget; ?>
    <?php
}
```

I did try to change the first line to

```
function __construct()
```

But that made my website unreachable.

Just wondering what the best way to proceed is?

cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...  :)

public function __construct() {